# Редирект на роут

Tags: php, laravel, route, роутинг

Как сделать в Laravel редирект на роут? 
Пробовал так:

```
return redirect()->route('add')
```

Выдаёт ошибку, что нет такого роута.
Но он есть.

```
Route::get('/add', function (){
    $model = new getInfoController();
    $category = $model->getCategory();
    $product = $model->getProduct();
    return view('admin/addCategory', compact("category","product"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите имя роута и все заработает

```
Route::get('/add', function (){
    $model = new getInfoController();
    $category = $model->getCategory();
    $product = $model->getProduct();
    return view('admin/addCategory', compact("category","product"));
})->name('add');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Прошляпил в документации данный момент)